# How to add line break in the ArcGIS Pro Geoprocessing window?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I'm looking to add a line break in the ArcGIS Pro geoprocessing window for a custom .pyt tool. In Arcmap, putting "\n" into an arcpy.AddMessage() statement works fine, but this does not work in ArcGIS Pro - the messages are reported in the geoprocessing window, but there is no line break. Any idea how this can be done in ArcGIS Pro?

This doesn't work:

```
    arcpy.AddMessage(observers)
    arcpy.AddMessage("\n")
    arcpy.AddMessage("\n")
    arcpy.AddMessage(targets)
```

And neither does this:

```
    arcpy.AddMessage(observers)
    arcpy.AddMessage("\r\n")
    arcpy.AddMessage("\r\n")
    arcpy.AddMessage(targets)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a message in the *Python window*, you need to use the Python `print` statement:

`print("some text")`

If you want to see your message in the *Geoprocessing pane*, your code should work. To see tool messages, hover over the progress bar, or click the pop-out button, as explained in the [Help](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geoprocessing/basics/run-geoprocessing-tools.htm):

> When a tool is running, a progress bar is displayed to show completion
>   percentage, and a cancel button is available to stop processing. You
>   can hover on the progress bar to display a popup window containing
>   comprehensive information about the tool that is running, such as
>   messages, execution time, and all tool settings.
>   You can also click the pop-out button Tool progress to see the same
>   information in a detached window, or expand the messages section to
>   view any geoprocessing messages.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work on the ArcGIS Pro Geoprocessing window.
arcpy.AddMessage does work, but not with '/n'

Comment: @Pitrako Jr So does it work?

Comment: No, it doesn't work